# Does hybrid remote supports only visual force page or lightning pages also?

Tags: mobile, hybrid, hybrid-remote

if i create a hybrid remote app will it support lightning pages.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official documentation, it only supports Visualforce pages.

> Hybrid apps fall into two categories:
>
> 1. Hybrid local—Hybrid local apps
>      are Web apps that run locally in the mobile container. These apps are
>      developed with the force.js library and store their HTML, JavaScript,
>      and CSS files on the user’s device.
> 2. Hybrid remote—Hybrid remote apps
>      deliver Visualforce pages through the mobile container. These apps
>      store some or all their HTML, JavaScript, and CSS files on the
>      Salesforce server.

You can add Lightning Apps to Visualforce pages but not sure if it will work on you Application. Refer [Hybrid Development Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/mobile_sdk_hybrid/mobilesdk_hybrid_getting_started) for more details.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the reply.
if the org uses only lightning, i.e lightning pages/components my app will not work?

Comment: @Madhu_W As per the information provided in trailhead, I don't think it will work. You can give it a try with simple Hello World app.

Comment: As of today only Visualforce is supported.  While not recommended, it may be possible to use Lightning running inside of a Visualforce container for very simple apps with minimal navigation.  More info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm